# Is there a library like RPX for Android?

Tags: android, facebook, openid, oauth, rpx

Does someone know of a library that is fairly "drop in" and allows you to easily put together multiple authentication options in an Android app to services like Facebook, OpenID, Twitter, etc. much like RPX does?

Answer (score 0):

Make a little HTML page with RPX embedded inside it (like a real site) inside your res folder and render it using WebView. You would need WebView anyways since as a requirement of OpenID and OpenAuth and everything needs you to go to their site. So in the end, you would need to load up a WebView to show the user that screen anyways.

Comment: Thank you. I have the feeling this is the right answer, but I'll clarify once I get a chance to actually check this out.